# naming a file on Google drive using a cell in spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have made a Google form that uploads a file. I want to automatically change the name of the file by using an entry from the form, or a cell content in the spreadsheet. Is this possible?

Comment: what did you try so far? :)

Comment: I have a google form, in which you have some entries like department name, course name ...etc. and a file upload. when I submit a response, the file name is go as :original file name" - "my driver name".png . I want to change automatically the file uploaded name to course name, or on other words to rename the response name to course name.

Comment: Check this out: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/126525/google-form-file-upload-change-file-name-to-match-form-value

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.
This isn't a free code writing service.
Nor is it a replacement for tutorials.
Please read [ask]. Then [edit] your question and add the code you've tried so far. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? 
If you don't know where to start coding, do a web search and read some tutorials first. 
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

**Changing the names of uploaded file using onFormSubmit event**

Put this in the spreadsheet with the linked sheet for your form

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var ft=e.values.slice(1);//this removes the timestamp
  var fA=ft[0].split(',');//this splits the file url's into an array
  for(var i=0;i<fA.length;i++) {
    var file=DriveApp.getFileById(fA[i].slice(fA[i].indexOf("=")+1));//get file by id by getting the id from the file.
    var t=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "HHmmss"); //add the date to the filename
    file.setName(Utilities.formatString('FileName-%s',t));//set the filename
    Utilities.sleep(2000);//I added this to insure that the filenames would bee different.
  } 
}
```

My form looks like:

[image]

The first column is a timestamp and the second column are the urls of the uploaded files in a comma delimited string.

[image]

> The files folder is loaded into a sub folder of the folder where the form was created that folder was named Form Title + " (File Responses)" and the files folder is named Question Name + " (File Responses)".

[onFormSubmit Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)