# Rename File Uploaded by Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, tags

I have a google form which includes a File Upload field.
I would like to use information in the form to rename the file being uploaded. I would like to do this using google script, but it is difficult to find any good information, so hoping someone can help me.

So far I am able to catch the onSubmit() method of the form, but I can't figure out what to do after this.

I have read many articles that all do it by using onSubmit() of the google sheet.

I have read many examples that use a Web app.....but typically have half information at best.

'''JavaScript

```
function onFormSubmit(e){
  // TODO - figure out authorizations (when I have 10 hours to read documentation that is not organized for a non-expert)
  // Email me the JSON of e so I can debug
  //MailApp.sendEmail('phermans@shipleyschool.org', 'test values', JSON.stringify(e));

  // TODO - figure out where I can see this logger.....seems to be a mystery
  // help with debugging by printing method in console
  // accessible by choosing View-->Logs and command+enter
  Logger.log("[MEHOD] onFormSubmit");

  Logger.log("authMode=%s, source.getId()=%s", e.authMode, e.source.getId());
  var items = e.response.getItemResponses();
  for (i in items){
    Logger.log("getItem().getTitle()=%s, getResponse()=%s", items[i].getItem().getTitle(), items[i].getResponse());
  }

  // Rename file based on info on the form
//    renameFile(itemResponse.getResponse(),"renamed_")


}

function renameFile(id, prefix) {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  file.setName(prefix + file.getName());
}
```

'''

No expectation yet, I just want to rename the file being uploaded using one of the fields that was filled in on the form.

Would love a working example if anyone has one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Forms Rename "File upload" File to "Question - Submitter"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57730428/google-forms-rename-file-upload-file-to-question-submitter)

Comment: Also take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58249241/naming-a-file-on-google-drive-using-a-cell-in-spreadsheet/58251431#58251431